# How to display the label text in a radio button in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

Using jQuery or JavaScript How can I display the text inside the labels. i.e. the text is 5 and 6

```
<label class="radio">
    <label style="display: none;">
        <input type="radio" name="x_keeper1_price" id="x_keeper1_price_0" value="21"/>
    </label>
    5
</label>

<label class="radio">
    <label style="display: none;">
        <label style="display: none;">
            <input type="radio" name="x_Defd5_price" id="x_Defd5_price_0" value="28"/>
        </label>
    </label>
    6
</label>


<div id="Price" class="Price">
   display 5 here 
</div>
<div id="Price2" class="Price2">
    display 6 here 
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/show or http://api.jquery.com/toggle -- don't nest `label` tags; instead, use `span` inside of a `label`.

Answer (score 0):

You HTML code is a bit weird, It's not a good idea to nest `label` tags, I've prepared a JSFiddle with my suggestion: http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ7Rg/2/

The modified HTML code:

```
<label id="l1" class="radio"><span style="display: none;">
    <input type="radio" name="x_keeper1_price" id="x_keeper1_price_0" value="21"/>
</span>5</label>

<label id="l2" class="radio"><label style="display: none;">
    <span style="display: none;"><input type="radio" name="x_Defd5_price" id="x_Defd5_price_0" value="28"/>
</span></label>6</label>

<div id="price" class="Price">
   display 5 here 
</div>
<div id="price2" class="Price2">
    display 6 here 
</div>
```

About the jQuery code, is quite easy, you can use the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method to read and set text content in a tag, for instance:

```
$('#price').text($('#l1').text());
$('#price2').text($('#l2').text());
```

> `text()` method description: *Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants.*

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to get your structure correct. Your HTML needs to be simple!!!

Basic label declaration:

```
<input type="radio" name="x_keeper1_price" id="x_keeper1_price_0" value="21">
<label for="x_keeper1_price_0">5</label>
```

Then if you want the label display text to show in a separate div do something like this:

```
//get the text from the lable
var lableText = $("label[for='x_keeper1_price_0']").text();

//put it inside the div
$("#Price").html("display " + lableText + " here");
```

Your question is a bit confusing so I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: The hmtl is auto generated and there are many radios, i cant chnage the whole code. I want a solution that can help in reading this text.